# Java - set printing page format

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I try to print a pdf using DocPrintJob but it won't fit to page and so, I have to manually print the page.
My pdf is already in Letter format.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
            PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration(), 200, 200,
                                  printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);

            if (service != null) {
                pras.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
                PageFormat page = new PageFormat();
/*              MediaSizeName media = MediaSize.findMedia(
                        (float) (page.getWidth() / 72.0),
                        (float) (page.getHeight() / 72.0), 
                        Size2DSyntax.INCH);
    */          
        //      pras.add(media);
                DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
                FileInputStream fis=null;
                File file = new File("test.pdf");
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream("test.pdf");

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();

               Doc document = null;
                document = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);


                try {
                    job.print(document, pras);
                } catch (PrintException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

As you can see, I've tried to use MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER but it just doesn't change anything.
Is there a way, also, to let the user select the Media size, there's no option in the print dialog?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the printer is taking the default paper based on the preferences you set, so if you set the preferences to use letter size it asks for a letter size page, by default it will print on A4 size paper.

Comment: I tried to print on Letter size: "pras.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);", but it doesn't work, so the default A4 size paper should not be used?

Comment: Show this sample code : http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?example_code_path=druid-org.dlib.gui.print-GraphicPrinter.java